# can't get printable directions using maps api with parameter pw=2 in url

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Why the feature of getting printable directions doesn't work anymore in google maps api? I used parameter pw=2 in the url to get directions with print option, but it now gives 404 error code. 
Example: http://maps.google.com/maps?dir=to&saddr=philadelphia&daddr=New+York&pw=2

Answer (score 0):

That was an undocumented function (at least by Google) of the "classic" google maps.  It no longer works.